# Error while adding Kotlin Multiplatform module as dependency: "Android project without build variants, and cannot be built."

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to add a Kotlin-Multiplatform library as a dependency to Android Project. I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: The module 'my-core' is an Android project without build
>   variants, and cannot be built. Please fix the module's configuration
>   in the build.gradle file and sync the project again.

The build.gradle for 'my-core' Kotlin-Multiplatform library is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.72'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.3.72'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

def ktor_version = '1.3.2'
def sqldeligh_version = '1.3.0'

group 'com.zoho.im.core'
version '0.0.1'

apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "0.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        //This is for MultiplatformSettings
        debug {
            // MPP libraries don't currently get this resolution automatically
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
    }
}

kotlin {
    android()
    // This is for iPhone simulator
    // Switch here to iosArm64 (or iosArm32) to build library for iPhone device
    iosX64("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework()
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib')
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version"
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqldeligh_version"
            }
        }
        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version"
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqldeligh_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

sqldelight {
    IMDatabase {
        packageName = "com.harley.core"
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

The android project that I imported into is just a simple fresh project. Please advice

Comment: You're using native serialization on commonMain

Comment: Thanks @KurtAcosta. What you've pointed is the issue. As I've pointed in my answer, those changes fixed the issue. But there are still some issues. Please check that https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038809/10506244

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you have a native dependency in commonMain sourceset: `io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version` 
The metadata system wouldn't be able to find an appropriate target for this dependency, which might lead to the error you demonstrate. This is just me speculating.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing, `io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version`
with `io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version` fixed the issue and the aar file is generated.

Side Note: this .aar file didn't pack androidMain dependencies. I had to manually add those dependencies(io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version, io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version, com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqldeligh_version) to consuming android project.